# Running prebuilt executable on iOS using swift 3 Xcode 8.2.1

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, xcode8, executable

I want to run prebuilt executables during the work cycle of the iOS application.

I have the executables built for different architecture (ARM in case when the app will be tested on the device and x86 in case of using simulator).

Any suggestions how it could be integrated in the application would be appreciated.

Comment: You do know you can't `fork`->`exec` or execute an `NSTask` in iOS? i.e. running an executable from an application in iOS won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to launch an executable on iOS from the main app - the sandbox simply won't allow it.

However, to accomplish what you're trying to do, you can create a fat binary from the individual executables - this binary will contain the executable code for all the architectures concerned - example using files called test.armv7 test.x86_64:

```
lipo -create -arch armv7 test.armv7 -arch x86_64 test.x86_64 -output test.fat
```

This binary *would* work on both platforms, if you could launch it; but as mentioned in the initial paragraph **you can't launch executables from iOS**.